# Stuck with finding the domain of a function with a logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

> Find the domain of the function $$g(x)=\log_3(x^2-1)$$

This is what I got so far:

$$\{ x\mid x^2-1>0\} =$$
$$\{ x\mid x^2>1\} =$$
$$\{ x\mid x>\sqrt { 1 } \}= $$

I don't know where to go from here to arrive at the correct answer... I would like a nudge in the right direction, if possible.

I would also like to know why it is that with any logarithmic function, $\log x$ is defined when $x>0$. It isn't really "clicking" in my head for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is in the argument of $\log_3$? It is $x^2 - 1$, right? So you need the values of $x$ such that: $$x^2 - 1 > 0$$
We have: $$x^2 - 1 > 0 \implies x^2 > 1 \implies |x| > 1$$
You got it wrong there because $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, so you let escape a few possibilities. Now, drawing the real line, it is easy to see that $|x| > 1$ happens if and only if $x > 1$, *or* $x < -1$. Ok?

---

We have that $\log_a b = x \iff a^x = b$, by definition. If $a > 0$ and $b < 0$, you get something positive equaling something negative.

Comment: It helps a lot to graph it and see what happens. I just want to be able to picture it mentally without the aid of a graphing calculator. So, just for clarification purposes... the absolute value of $x$ is less than $-1$ and greater than $1$

Thus,

$(-\infty ,-1)\cup (1,\infty )$

Comment: Think as it like this: $|a -b|$ is the distance from $a$ to $b$, in the real line. So, $|x| = |x - 0|$ is the distance from $x$ to the origin. What are the numbers $x$ which distance from the origin is more than $1$ (to both sides of the line)?

Answer (score 3):

$x^2>1 \iff (x<-1$ or $x>1$) Alternatively, look at the graph of $x^2-1$ and see where it is above the $x-$axis

To answer your other question, logarithms are exponents. $\log_3(x)$ is the exponent $y$ which makes $3^y=x$. Now if $x$ were negative, say $x=-1$, then what is the exponent $y$ such that $3^y=-1.$ Of course **there is none**. So $\log_3(-1)$ doesnt make sense!